# CSS Column content breaking

Tags: html, css

I'm working with a sub-menu that have accordion in it. The menu is in ul/li.

I made the main ul of the sub-menu this way and the display resultat is exactly what I want:

```
.main-navigation #cssmenu ul > #menu-item-3465 > ul {
    column-count:3; 
    column-rule:2px solid #fff;
    column-fill:auto;
    column-gap:30px;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
}
```

[image: correct menu]

But, when we open an accordion in that sub-menu, the column break and the content goes in the rest of the other columns:

[image: opened accordion screwed menu]

I want the columns to stay the same even if we open the accordion.

I tried things like column-break-inside on the li, but it's not working at all.

I also tried with flexbox, but I have the exact same problem.

I don't know if there is something I can do to make it works, or we need to rethink our menu.

Need some suggestions please.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to share your code. 1 CSS class is not enough. Without seeing the HTML+CSS code we can't help

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve your problem You need to apply **CSS column breaks**. Here's the link that have pretty much all the methods you might need: https://www.quirksmode.org/css/columns/breaks.html
Choose the one that satisfies Your sub-menu.

Answer (score 0):

Already tried the column breaks. It didn't work.

I did that on the li like this :

```
.main-navigation #cssmenu ul #menu-item-3465 ul li {
    -webkit-column-break-inside:avoid;
    page-break-inside:avoid;
    break-inside:avoid; 
}
```

The HTML goes like this

```
<li id="menu-item-3465" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a style="text-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35) 0px 1px 0px;"><span style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);">Services</span><span class="holder" style="border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.35);"></span></a>
<ul style="display: none;">
    <li id="menu-item-3975" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/administratif-et-constitutionnel/"><span>Administratif et constitutionnel</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3967" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/acces-a-linformation-et-protection-des-renseignements-personnels-2/"><span>Accès à l’information et protection des renseignements personnels</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3974" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/administratif/"><span>Administratif</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4065" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/appel-doffres-et-soumissions-2/"><span>Appel d’offres et soumissions</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3996" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/constitutionnel/"><span>Constitutionnel</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3999" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/controle-judiciaire-et-responsabilite-de-letat/"><span>Contrôle judiciaire et responsabilité de l’État</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4002" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/corporations-professionnelles/"><span>Corporations professionnelles</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4011" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/droit-electoral/"><span>Droit électoral</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4013" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/droits-et-libertes/"><span>Droits et libertés</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4018" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/energie/"><span>Énergie</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4021" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/ethique-et-deontologie/"><span>Éthique et déontologie</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/gouvernance-et-societes-detat/"><span>Gouvernance et sociétés d’État</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4034" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/legislation-et-reglementation/"><span>Législation et réglementation</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4045" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/organismes-publics-et-parapublics/"><span>Organismes publics et parapublics</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4064" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/zonage-agricole/"><span>Zonage agricole</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3976" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/affaires/"><span>Affaires</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3973" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/achat-et-vente-dentreprise/"><span>Achat et vente d’entreprise</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4001" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/convention-entre-actionnaires-et-dassocies/"><span>Convention entre actionnaires et d’associés</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/fusion-et-acquisition/"><span>Fusion et acquisition</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4038" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/litige-commercial/"><span>Litige commercial</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4049" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/redaction-interpretation-et-negociation-de-documents/"><span>Rédaction, interprétation et négociation de documents</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4051" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/reorganisation-corporative/"><span>Réorganisation corporative</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4059" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/transactions-immobilieres-et-baux-commerciaux/"><span>Transactions immobilières et baux commerciaux</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4060" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/transfert-dentreprise-et-releve/"><span>Transfert d’entreprise et relève</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3978" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/appel-doffres-et-soumissions-2/"><span>Appel d’offres et soumissions</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3979" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/arbitrage-et-mediation/"><span>Arbitrage et médiation</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3952" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-invalidite/"><span>Assurance invalidité</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3988" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurances/"><span>Assurances</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3981" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-de-biens/"><span>Assurance de biens</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3982" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-de-personne/"><span>Assurance de personne</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3983" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-dommages/"><span>Assurance dommages</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3984" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-habitation/"><span>Assurance habitation</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3986" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-responsabilite/"><span>Assurance responsabilité</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4066" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-responsabilite/"><span>Assurance responsabilité</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3987" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assurance-vie/"><span>Assurance-vie</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3997" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/construction/"><span>Construction</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4003" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/courtiers-dassurance-et-distribution-de-produits-dassurance/"><span>Courtiers d’assurance et distribution de produits d’assurance</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4004" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/couverture-dassurance/"><span>Couverture d’assurance</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4010" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/droit-des-transports-et-connaissements/"><span>Droit des transports et connaissements</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4022" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/exclusion/"><span>Exclusion</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/formation-et-incorporation-de-mutuelles-dassurance/"><span>Formation et incorporation de mutuelles d’assurance</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/incendie/"><span>Incendie</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/lettre-de-reserve/"><span>Lettre de réserve</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4037" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/litige-aupres-de-lautorite-des-marches-financiers/"><span>Litige auprès de l’Autorité des marchés financiers</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4044" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/obligation-de-defendre-en-assurance-de-responsabilite/"><span>Obligation de défendre en assurance de responsabilité</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4047" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/recours-collectifs/"><span>Recours collectifs</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4048" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/redaction-et-interpretation-de-polices-dassurance/"><span>Rédaction et interprétation de polices d’assurance</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4053" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-de-produit-et-du-fabricant/"><span>Responsabilité de produit et du fabricant</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4054" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-des-administrateurs-et-dirigeants/"><span>Responsabilité des administrateurs et dirigeants</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4055" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-environnementale-et-pollution/"><span>Responsabilité environnementale et pollution</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4056" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-municipale/"><span>Responsabilité municipale</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4057" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-professionnelle/"><span>Responsabilité professionnelle</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4063" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/vices-caches/"><span>Vices cachés</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3990" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/bancaire-et-services-financiers/"><span>Bancaire et services financiers</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3958" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a><span>Blessures corporelles</span></a>
    <ul style="display: none;">
        <li id="menu-item-3970" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/accidents-de-la-construction/"><span>Accidents de la construction</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3969" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/accidents-daviation/"><span>Accidents d’aviation</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3972" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/accidents-nautiques/"><span>Accidents nautiques</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3992" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/blessures-sportives-accidents-recreatifs/"><span>Blessures sportives / accidents récréatifs</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3994" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/chutes/"><span>Chutes</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4005" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/defauts-de-fabrication/"><span>Défauts de fabrication</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4008" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/dommages-catastrophiques/"><span>Dommages catastrophiques</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4041" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/morsures-de-chiens/"><span>Morsures de chiens</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3995" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/civil/"><span>Civil</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3993" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/bornage/"><span>Bornage</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4009" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/droit-de-la-consommation/"><span>Droit de la consommation</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4040" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/litiges-successoraux/"><span>Litiges successoraux</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4061" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/tutelle-et-regime-de-protection/"><span>Tutelle et régime de protection</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-4007" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/disciplinaire-et-penal/"><span>Disciplinaire et pénal</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4017" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/electoral/"><span>Électoral</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3980" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/assemblees-deliberantes/"><span>Assemblées délibérantes</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4014" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/elections-municipales/"><span>Élections municipales</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4015" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/elections-provinciales/"><span>Élections provinciales</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4016" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/elections-scolaires/"><span>Élections scolaires</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3955" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/environnement-2/"><span>Environnement</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4020" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/erreurs-medicales/"><span>Erreurs médicales</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3956" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/expropriation-2/"><span>Expropriation</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4024" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/faillite-et-insolvabilite/"><span>Faillite et insolvabilité</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4032" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/immobilier-et-construction/"><span>Immobilier et construction</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-4077" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/construction-2/"><span>Construction</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/immobilier/"><span>Immobilier</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3957" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/lettres-de-change/"><span>Lettres de change</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-3954" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/municipal-2/"><span>Municipal</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4046" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/propriete-intellectuelle/"><span>Propriété intellectuelle</span></a></li>
    <li id="menu-item-4052" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-civile/"><span>Responsabilité civile</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-4083" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/blessures-corporelles/"><span>Blessures corporelles</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4006" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/diffamation/"><span>Diffamation</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4039" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/litiges/"><span>Litiges</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4079" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/recours-collectifs/"><span>Recours collectifs</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4080" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-de-produit-et-du-fabricant/"><span>Responsabilité de produit et du fabricant</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4078" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-municipale/"><span>Responsabilité municipale</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-4081" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/responsabilite-professionnelle/"><span>Responsabilité professionnelle</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="menu-item-3964" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/travail/"><span>Travail</span></a>
    <ul style="">
        <li id="menu-item-3971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/accidents-de-travail-et-maladie-professionnelle/"><span>Accidents de travail et maladie professionnelle</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3962" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/contrat-individuel-de-travail/"><span>Contrat individuel de travail</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3961" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/convention-collective/"><span>Convention collective</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3960" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/normes-du-travail/"><span>Normes du travail</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-3959" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-services_jur"><a href="http://dev-medias.com/tbml/services_jur/relations-de-travail-2/"><span>Relations de travail</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</li>
```